# Отследить нахождение пользователя на странице сайта

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице сайта имеется блок со счетчиком.
Как сделать, чтобы блок скрывался после того, как пользователь переключился на эту страницу.
Допусти открыл он страницу, после переключился на другую вкладку браузера, в этот момент на странице искомого сайта, запустился счетчик, пользователь переключается и после 3 секунд - блок со счетчиком пропадает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/) маньяки Javascript'а пишут, что Chrome и FireFox не всегда запускают события `blur` / `focus`, когда пользователь переключает табы, и советуют использовать HTML5 [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).